# How to run the first function in a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

At the moment, I want to make a simple JavaScript application. For this I am using an HTML page, a canvas and the JavaScript file that goes with it.

In the code there would be a `setup()` function, this function will translate the context to the middle/bottom of the canvas on startup. After this function, the `main()` function is called and will be running in a loop.

Now I was wondering: what would be the proper way to call this `setup()` function?
(e.g. adding a `window.requestAnimationFrame(setup)` at the bottom of the JavaScript code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put `setup()` at the bottom of your js file